# Electromagnet by voltage, current or power?

Tags: electromagnetism, home-experiment

I have coil with $1 \Omega$ resistance.

I want to assemble circuit to power coil and control amount of current flow with MOSFET.

But before that I'd like to know. What does affect on electromagnet field ?

Current or power ?

For example:

- If Current flow, then $1A$ and $1V$, would be the same as $1A$ and $10V$.
- If Power, then $1A$ and $5V$ would be the same as $0.25A$ and $20V$.

Comment: If the coil resistance is fixed, how can you have the situations described? Only the 1 V and 1A satisfy the condition.

Comment: According to Ohm law, $V/I = R $ if R is fixed.

Comment: Do you mean the magnetic field produced by an electromagnet? An electromagnetic field is something very different.

Comment: Yes, magnet field produced by a electromagnet.

Comment: R is fixed, but e.g. I have power supply 120 W, 12V, max 10A, I don't need 10 A, so I can reduce current to 1.5A with 12V by MOSFET. And I have 1.5V AA alkaline battery with 1.5A 1.5V. Will magnet field be same with 1.5A 1.5V from alkaline battery and 1.5A 12V from power supply with current controlled by MOSFET ?

Comment: The voltage across the 1 ohm resistor will be the same if the current is the same. No matter what you do with the MOSFET

Answer (score 2):

It is actually current and the number of times that current loops around. The number of loop essentially lets the magnetic field of that same current stack up on itself.

It is impractical to have one loop with 1000A running through it, but it is much more practical to have 10A running through 100 loops so that the magnetic field generated by that current is stacked 100 times to get the same result.

Of course, more loops means more wire which means more resistance which means more voltage to push the same current which means more power, because nothing is free...although there are superconducting coils...I don't really understand how that works power-wise. I assume it has something to do with the field performing work vs no work, and a regular magnet always has some work being done due to resistance even if the magnetic field is performing no work.